# javascript - insert div after elements with a certain class on mouseover

Tags: javascript

I know that there is a really simple jQuery way to to this, but now I would like to understand why my code is not working properly:

```
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

var menuHelp = document.querySelector(".menu_help");


for (var i = 0;i<menuHelp.length;i++){

menuHelp[i].onmouseenter = function(){
    menuHelpPopup = document.createElement("div");
    menuHelpPopup.setAttribute('class','menu_help_popup');
    menuHelpPopup.innerHTML = "test";
    insertAfter(menuHelp[i], menuHelpPopup);
}

menuHelp[i].onmouseleave = function(){
    menuHelpPopup.remove();
}

}
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a popup and insert it after elements with a certain class when mouseover on them..

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/r5e8rvkg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please make sure menuHelp is a nodeList, so you should use document.querySelectorAll;
2. When the mouse enter, the value of i is menuHelp.length. so you should use this, like insertAfter(this, menuHelpPopup)

Answer (score 1):

I used [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) and it seemed to have worked.

```
var menuHelp = document.getElementsByClassName('menu_help');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout here: http://jsfiddle.net/r5e8rvkg/1/

First, use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`.

More importantly, you need to take care that in your code:

```
menuHelp[i].onmouseenter = function(){
    menuHelpPopup = document.createElement("div");
    menuHelpPopup.setAttribute('class','menu_help_popup');
    menuHelpPopup.innerHTML = "test";
    insertAfter(menuHelp[i], menuHelpPopup);
}
```

The value `i` would not be passed in correctly because the event `onmouseenter` is Async. When the function is called, the value of i is actually `i === menuHelp.length`, which results in `menuHelp[i] === undefined`.

You need to use [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures), as shown in [my JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/r5e8rvkg/1/).

Answer (score 0):

The [document.querySelector()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) method returns only the first element with the specified selector. To get each element with class 'menu_help', you need to use the [document.querySelectorAll()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) method.

In other words, replace:

```
    var menuHelp = document.querySelector(".menu_help");
```

With

```
    var menuHelp = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_help");
```